# Can I use Udemy logo in my own application (Udemy Downloader)

Tags: branding, open-source, copyright

I recently created a desktop application that lets you download your subscribed  courses on `Udemy`. (https://www.udemy.com)

I have the application source code on `Github`.

In my application, I have a login form with `Udemy logo` which asks user to login to their `Udemy` account so that they can access the subscribed courses. I am not sure if it is legal/allowed to use the `logo` for this purpose. I tried to research a bit about this and found that in some cases  I can use the `logo` but it shouldn't mislead users that know the company by its logo on what the company is all about. However, I would still like to confirm it here as I am confused whether my application falls in the misleading category or not and just to be be sure if I have read it right.

I am planning to use the `logo` as my application's icon also (depending upon if it is allowed).

Here is the link to `Github` repository https://github.com/FaisalUmair/udemy-downloader-gui

and the logo I am talking about https://www.udemy.com/staticx/udemy/images/v5/logo-green.svg

## UPDATE:

**For those who are interested**

I went ahead and contacted udemy as per suggested answer and comments. This is the reply I got.

```
Hi there,

Thank you for your email and it would be my pleasure to help.

Unfortunately, we don't allow use of the Udemy logo on outside websites 
or social media platforms.

Thank you for checking.
```

Comment: This is a legal issue, you’ll need to contact Udemy for permission most likely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I will end up using a custom made logo. But if I try to edit the Udemy logo and change it, does that still stand illegal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK if you read the [Terms of Use for Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/terms/), you'll find in the Trademark Section this quote:

> The trademarks, service marks, and logos (the "Trademarks") used and displayed through Our Services or in any Company Content are Our registered or unregistered Trademarks or of Our suppliers or third parties and are protected pursuant to U.S. and foreign trademark laws. All rights are reserved and You may not alter or obscure the Trademarks, or link to them without Our prior approval

So you'll definitely have to ask Udemy for permission, and no, you can't edit the logo, that's trademark infringement.